# Trouble generating new data, plotting with matplotlib, and simultaneously sending the data over a serial connection

Tags: python, matplotlib, serial-port, pyserial

I'm sending data over serial from Python to an Arduino, and I have two chunks of code that work fine separately:

- The first piece generates new data and plots it using matplotlib every time I press enter.
- The second piece generates new data and sends it via the serial port (using `with serial.Serial`) every time I press enter.

When I combine the two pieces, to generate new data, plot it, and send it every time I press enter, the data still sends fine, but the matplotlib figure remains blank until I terminate the code, at which point it plots the last set of generated data. Is there a way to do all of these things at the same time? Code included below (I've replaced all the data generation code with just a call to np.random for clarity).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import serial

with serial.Serial(port='COM7', baudrate=115200, timeout=0.5) as arduino:
    # Initialize figure
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    
    while True:
        # Clear axes and wait for user go-ahead
        ax.cla()
        command = input()
        if command == 'x':
            break

        # Generate data and plot
        data = np.random.rand(6)
        ax.plot(data)

        # Send data to arduino and read back response
        for val in data:
            arduino.write(str(val).encode())
            arduino.write('\n'.encode())
        for i in range(data.size):
            received_data = arduino.readline()
            print(received_data.decode('utf-8').strip())
```

Comment: After `ax.plot`, try adding `plt.pause(0.01)`. That should force the figure to draw and show.

Comment: Both plt.pause() and plt.ion() from below resolved it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `plt.ion()` to make sure matplotlib is in interactive mode

- https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/interactive.html#interactive-mode

This should make sure that the figure does not block once it's shown and changes are immediately drawn.